# using a javascript function in a Knockout style binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I have an HTML page where I have applied some Knockout bindings to some elements:

```
<td class="tepvval" data-bind="text: tepv"></td>
<td class="dateval" data-bind="text: dueIn(due)"></td>
```

In the second element, I call a function to populate the data content of the element. I'm trying to do the same for the style of the element, but I'm having issues. I need to call a function to compute the difference between the date (due) and today, and then return the color I want to use for the background of the element - green is due more than 30 days, yellow is 30-15 days, orange 15-1 days, red is overdue.

I tried using

```
<td class="dateval" data-bind="text: dueIn(due), 
                               style: { backgroundColor: colorDue(due) }"></td>
```

but that doesn't work.

what am I missing in the syntax?

here is the function code I'm calling in colorDue:

```
function colorDue(due) {    
    rd = 1;     
    od = 15;    
    yd = 30; 
    var difference = dateDiff(due);  
    if (difference>yd) { color="green"; }  
    else if (yd>difference && difference>od) { color="yellow"; }  
    else if (od>difference && difference>rd) { color="orange"; } 
    else if (difference <=rd) { color="red"; } 
    return color; 
}  

function dateDiff(due) {    
    var  df, ymd, now, dateStr, diff;   
    df = due.split(" ");    
    ymd = df[0].split("-");     
    now = new Date();   
    dateStr = new Date(ymd[0],ymd[1],ymd[2],17,0,0);    
    diff = dateStr.getTime()-now.getTime();     
    diff = diff/86400000; 
    return diff; 
}
```

Comment: Can I see the controller this view is bound to?

Comment: I would make sure to put the function in your viewmodel and reference it with `$root`. Something [along the lines of this](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/M9wg7/). If the coloring still is off, I'd suspect `dateDiff`

Comment: Yes- the colorStyle vs colorDue was just a transcription typo. I'll try the $root and see if that works. I don't think there's any issue with dateDiff - I use it in the text: binding for the element and it works just fine.

Comment: You are not *required* do it that way, but generally you'll want to encapsulate functions in your viewmodel. I updated my fiddle to show a few different approaches.

Comment: Maybe you need to debug your function. A very basic example is working for me. http://jsfiddle.net/PtNj4/

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
dateStr = new Date(ymd[0],ymd[1],ymd[2],17,0,0);
```

In js (don't ask why), month starts at 0 (while day and year starts at 1...). See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

> month Integer value representing the month, beginning with 0 for
>   January to 11 for December.

So you need a `-1` here:

```
dateStr = new Date(ymd[0],ymd[1] -1,ymd[2],17,0,0);
```

There are other stuff that you should change here, like declaring your variables local:

```
function colorDue(due) {    
    var rd = 1;     
    var od = 15;    
    var yd = 30; 
    var color = "";
    //...
}
```